# UItextView Delegate methods not called inside subview

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uitextfield

In brief:

In ClassA_VC I do:

```
ClassB_VC *classB_VC=[ClassB_VC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClassB_VC" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:classB_VC.view];
```

Then in ClassB_VC I have an UITextField. I set the delegate connection between textfield and File's owner in IB, I added  in @interface declaration and I wrote the protocol methods (textFieldDidEndEditing, textFieldDidBeginEditing, etc...) as usual.

This should work but I got an Exception when I touch the textfield. It seems textfield is not reaching its delegate.

However, if I present the view using presentModalViewController, everything works fine. I'd prefer not having to do it so because these views are into a tabViewController and I'd like not hiding the tabBar when showing.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say. My english is not very good.

Comment: A full exception message would be helpful. As all the methods of the UITextFieldDelegate are optional, the protocol reference at the interface file or misspelling the delegate methods signature should not be a problem, it looks more like a memory issue.

Comment: Well, that's the point. There's no message, just freezes. All I got is the trace of the Thread 1 showing these last lines: 0 objc_msgSend  1 -[UITextField canBecomeFirstResponder]  2-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] 3 -[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary]  It seems the added view is not the first responder. I've tried to force [self.view becomeFirstResponder] in viewDidLoad but still the same. If I unlink UITextField from delegate it doesn't crash but I can't hide keyboard, etc...

Comment: You might have created an infinite loop somewhere at the delegate methods, please try to comment all of them. If the issue remains, you'll want to check the InterfaceBuilder connections, it is smart enough not to let you to link UITextField outlet to other type outlets, but you might have changed the outlet class manually after created the connection. Or do you set anything to this outlet manually in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you retain ClassB_VC in ClassA_VC?

Comment: Yes!. That do the trick. It seems obvious... NOW. :D I don't understand why it this happening anyway. The view is not unloaded nor removed from screen. :|

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: The views are retained being added to other views, the second view controller, which is also the textView delegate, is not retained by anything. So what happens is that viewController was deallocated - it released it's outlets, but they are in the view's stack which retains them, that's how the views **are not** deallocated but the view controller as a delegate **is** deallocated. When you are displaying viewController's view it as modal, the controller gets retained and the controller is not deallocated. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, A-Live. It's clear now. :D

Answer (score 0):

remove the delegate from interface builder and do this :

```
ClassB_VC *classB_VC=[ClassB_VC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClassB_VC" bundle:nil];
[classB_VC.yourTextField setDelegate:classB_VC];
[self.view addSubview:classB_VC.view];
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: It didn't work. I've already had this problem time ago and I had to include the view and methods from ClassB into ClassA and keep it hidden until it was needed. It seems very messy for me. It must be very, very easy to deal with this problem but I'm missing something obvious here.